# Do you need to follow manual linking steps for Android with React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, autolink

When I'm adding third party components to React Native apps, such as [this one](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info), it often says that because of auto-linking, you do not have to follow the manual linking steps. For Android, I notice that none of the code added in the manual linking steps, such as adding code to `MainApplication.java`, none of it gets added automatically.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Do I need to do the manual linking steps for Android despite auto-linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for android, it doesn't need linking. since react-native 0.6, the auto-link doesn't directly add int `MainApplication.java`.

in android settings.gradle, you can see this code:

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
```

in the `native_modules.gradle` it will add the package. the code is complex. I read some days, only know a little. but we can get from the name and comment.

```
def generatedFileName = "PackageList.java"
def generatedFilePackage = "com.facebook.react"
...
  /**
   * Include the react native modules android projects and specify their project directory
   */
  void addReactNativeModuleProjects(DefaultSettings defaultSettings) 

  //here are add the package list
  /**
   * Adds the react native modules as dependencies to the users `app` project
   */
  void addReactNativeModuleDependencies(Project appProject)

  /**
   * Code-gen a java file with all the detected ReactNativePackage instances automatically added
   *
   * @param outputDir
   * @param generatedFileName
   * @param generatedFileContentsTemplate
   */
  void generatePackagesFile(File outputDir, String generatedFileName, String 
  generatedFileContentsTemplate)
```

in the end,  we only should know **we don't need the link**.

Comment: Hi Lenoarod, thanks for your reply. What I'm understanding from this is that when previously we would add code to `MainApplication.java` etc, when the app builds it looks at those files and adds code to build files that links the modules. With auto-linking, the code in `native_modules.gradle` adds the code to the build files, linking the modules, so it doesn't need any code from `MainApplication.java` etc to do it. Am I understanding that right? If so, there might be modules that this auto-linking doesn't work for, such that we WOULD have to manually link in `MainApplication.java` etc. Right?

Comment: yes, some module auto link don not support，we will  do  it  as before.  we have to  add  it manually.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.